# Dovecot trying to authenticate external users

Tags: postfix, dovecot, postfwd

I am using dovecot version 2.3.4.1 with SQL authentication and it works perfectly fine.
I see in the logs though that when I use a PHP script to email a list of users, that dovecot is trying to authenticate the recipients? I might be wrong in reading the log but if the email is leaving from info@example.com to test@yahoo.com, why would dovecot try to authenticate test@yahoo.com? The following are the relevant entries in the log

```
mail postfix/smtpd[9532]: connect from server1.example.com[192.168.2.111]
mail postfwd2/policy[8667]: [RULES] rule=0, id=RULE001, client=server1.example.com[192.168.2.111], sender=<info@example.com>, recipient=<test@yahoo.com>, helo=<server1.example.com>, proto=ESMTP, state=RCPT, delay=0.00s, hits=RULE001, action=dunno
mail dovecot: auth-worker(13507): sql(test@yahoo.com): unknown user
mail postfix/smtpd[9532]: DE059240031: client=server1.example.com[192.168.2.111]
mail postfix/cleanup[9534]: DE059240031: message-id=<11ac7c97d4a0afc4d0bc4832674457fe@server1.example.com>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

main.cf

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 25600000
milter_mail_macros = i {mail_addr} {client_addr} {client_name} {auth_authen}
mydestination = $myhostname, mail.example.com, mail3.example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost
myhostname = mail.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.2.0/24
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:11332
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:11332
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_policy_service unix:private/quota-status
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10040
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
soft_bounce = no
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: 127.0.0.1:10040_time_limit=3600
```

master.cf

```
smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
submission inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -o syslog_name=postfix/submission -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions= -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
pickup     unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq      unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog    unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
```

Comment: This is likely easier to answer if you [add your postfix configuration](https://serverfault.com/tags/postfix/info), both postfix and attached policy/milter services could be configured for such lookups.

Comment: I have added the config files as requested. Thanks

Comment: Well, what is that milter at `inet:127.0.0.1:11332` and what is that policy service at `inet:127.0.0.1:10040` supposed to do? Are you certain both are configured appropriately for handling both external receipts and internal mail submission?

Comment: On 11332 I have rspamd running. The culprit might be postfwd that I have running on 10040. pstfwd.cf looks like this:
```&&TRUSTED_NETS{
        client_address=192.168.2.98/32
        client_address=192.168.2.100/32
        client_address=192.168.2.177/32
}
id=RULE001;&&TRUSTED_NETS;action=dunno
id=RULE009;action=rate(sender/150/3600/421 4.7.1 - Sorry, exceeded 100 messages in 60 minutes.)```